# ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client on visual studio code

Tags: mysql, sql-server, visual-studio-code, web-development-server

I am trying to run MySQL from the visual studio code. I downloaded the extension called MySQL, to connect my SQL server with visual studio. After I fill out the localhost, port, username, and password, the SQL section shows me an error that is in the title above. I ran the server and created a database from the MySQL client command. However, I can't figure it out. Anyone who ran into the same problem as I am? If so, could you give me some tips to solve it? (I am basically asking how to set up the MySQL in visual studio code.) I am leaving a reference image, so that you may understand what I am trying to express here.
**Also how do I clear screen in MySQL in client command?**[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem. in order to solve it, try to use on your MySQL client:

```
ALTER USER '<your_user>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<your_password>'
```

Like this:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '1234'
```

Then try the connection again no VS Code! That solved for me.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you show two different solutions here and which should I use?

Comment: Is the same, the second one is an example of usage, the first one is a template

Comment: I had to remove the @'localhost' part of it to work for me. 

So:
ALTER USER 'root' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'my_passwd'